# Kubespray: Can't run upgrade due to cordon failing on istiod

Tags: kubernetes, kubespray

I am running Kubespray v.2.19.0 on 4 bare metal servers running Ubuntu 20.04.  The 4 servers are setup as one master node and 3 worker nodes.  It's a small cluster I run at my house to run my own compute and to "play"

I am trying to run a upgrade using:

```
ansible-playbook -kK -i inventory/mycluster/hosts.yaml upgrade-cluster.yml --become --become-user=root -e ignore_assert_errors=yes
```

But when it tries to cordon off the master node (server name is `server`) I get the following:

```
TASK [upgrade/pre-upgrade : Drain node] ****************************************
fatal: [server -> server]: FAILED! => {"attempts": 3, "changed": true, "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/kubectl", "--kubeconfig", "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf", "drain", "--force", "--ignore-daemonsets", "--grace-period", "300", "--timeout", "360s", "--delete-emptydir-data", "server"], "delta": "0:06:02.042964", "end": "2023-05-28 10:14:07.440240", "failed_when_result": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2023-05-28 10:08:05.397276", "stderr": "WARNING: ignoring DaemonSet-managed Pods: ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller-rmdtj, kube-system/calico-node-rmdjg, kube-system/kube-proxy-fb6ff, kube-system/nodelocaldns-w5tzq\nerror when evicting pods/\"istiod-6b56cffbd9-thdjl\" -n \"istio-system\" (will retry after 5s): Cannot evict pod as it would violate the pod's disruption budget.\nerror when evicting pods/\"istiod-6b56cffbd9-thdjl\" -n \"istio-system\" (will retry after 5s):...
```

Is there some flag I can pass to the upgrade to tell it to ignore the distribution budget or to ignore those errors altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to create a workaround I'd suggest to resolve the actual problem.

You have two options. You can either increase the replicas to 2. Or you can disable pod disruption budget.

Since you only run a home lab I'd take option two to not waste resources on a second pod that you probably don't need.

Not clear how you installed istio, but that's how you do it using an operator manifest:

```yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1 
kind: IstioOperator 
spec: 
  profile: default # your profile
  tag: 1.17.2 # your version 
  values: 
    global: 
      defaultPodDisruptionBudget: 
        enabled: false
```

Save it to a file like `config.yaml` and install it with `istioctl install -f config.yaml`.

Comment: Perfect. I installed Istio through Kubespray.  I'll have to fiddle with it a bit to see how to get that feature turned off.